# TypeError when extracting float key pair value from JSON response

Tags: python, typeerror, key-pair

**Background -** I have a function that takes a variable called `api_response` (which itself was formatted using `api_response = json.loads(response.text)` from another function and tries to extract 2x key pair values from it - namely `id` and `percent_complete` and print them.

**Function** -

```
def unpack_response():
    api_response = api_call()
# Code Block # 1
    while "meta" not in api_response:
        id_value = "id"
        res1 = [val[id_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if id_value in val]
        id_value = "".join(res1)
        percent_value = "percent_complete"
        # The following line of code is referenced in the TypeError  
        res2 = [val['attributes'][percent_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if percent_value in val['attributes']]
        percent_value = "".join(res2)
        print(f' Your data requested, associated with ID: {id_value} is {percent_value} complete!')
        time.sleep(5)
        continue
# Code Block # 2
    if "meta" in api_response:
        print(api_response)
unpack_response()
```

**JSON response (`api_response`)** -

```
{'data': {'id': '2205853', 'type': 'jobs', 'attributes': {'job_type': 'PORTFOLIO_VIEW_RESULTS', 'started_at': '2021-12-17T02:53:48Z', 'parameters': {'end_date': '2021-12-14', 'output_type': 'json', 'view_id': 304078, 'portfolio_id': 1, 'portfolio_type': 'firm', 'start_date': '2021-12-14'}, 'percent_complete': 0.19, 'status': 'In Progress'}, 'relationships': {'creator': {'links': {'self': '/v1/jobs/2205853/relationships/creator', 'related': '/v1/jobs/2205853/creator'}, 'data': {'type': 'users', 'id': '731221'}}}, 'links': {'self': '/v1/jobs/2205853'}}, 'included': []}
```

**Issue** - the function returns the `id` key value pair without issue and prints (providing I remove all `percent_complete`-related code), however the `"percent_complete"` key pair value is causing the following `TypeError`.

**Error** -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-8a61597dcee6> in <module>
     16     if "meta" in api_response:
     17         print(api_response)
---> 18 unpack_response()

<ipython-input-38-8a61597dcee6> in unpack_response()
      8         percent_value = "percent_complete"
      9 #         res2 = [val['attributes'][percent_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if percent_value in val['attributes']]
---> 10         res2 = [val['attributes'].get(percent_value, '') for key, val in api_response.items()]
     11         percent_value = "".join(res2)
     12         print(f' Your data requested, associated with ID: {id_value} is {percent_value} complete!')

<ipython-input-38-8a61597dcee6> in <listcomp>(.0)
      8         percent_value = "percent_complete"
      9 #         res2 = [val['attributes'][percent_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if percent_value in val['attributes']]
---> 10         res2 = [val['attributes'].get(percent_value, '') for key, val in api_response.items()]
     11         percent_value = "".join(res2)
     12         print(f' Your data requested, associated with ID: {id_value} is {percent_value} complete!')

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can anyone help me understand why the `id` returns without issue (providing I remove all `percent_complete`-related code), and yet the key pair value of `percent_complete` does not. Is this something to do with the key pair value being a float?

Comment: You don't need `continue` at the bottom of a loop. Loops automatically repeat unless you break out.

Comment: The value of the `included` key of `api_response` is a list, not a dictionary. You can't use `val['attributes']` when `val` is a list.

Comment: The reason it works for `id` is because you have the `if id_value in val` condition. The `in` operator works for both dictionaries and lists. The condition fails for the list, so it never tries to execute `val[id_value]`

Comment: I appreciate your thoughtful input. I am relatively new to Python @Barmer However, I don't understand your point, especially the relevance of `included` (which I am not trying to access). I have tried `percent_complete` with that condition, with the same result `res2 = [val['attributes'][percent_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if percent_value in val['attributes']]` I have updated the function to show this.

Comment: Is there any reason why you chose to access the data using a list comprehension rather than using `api_response["data"]["attributes"]`? Your `res2 = ...` code doesn't check for if `"attributes"` is in `val`, which is why it ends up accessing the `"included"` key. The error looks like it's trying to access `api_response["included"]["attributes"]`, which will fail because `included` is a list.

Comment: You're looping over all the elements of the `api_response` dictionary. There are two keys and values. The `data` key has a dictionary as its value, and that has an `attributes` key. The `included` key has a list as its value, and that gets an error when you try to access its `attributes` key.

Comment: I've managed to return the value, however it seems to be returning twice, despite there only being a single value. Code = `res = [tuple(api_response["data"]["attributes"].get("percent_complete", '') for key, val in api_response.items())]` Output = `[(0.0, 0.0)]`. I turned to a tuple, as otherwise you get a `<generator object <genexpr>`. Any suggestions why I am seeing 2 values?

Comment: `api_response.items()` returns two items. The list comprehension creates an element for each of those items.

Comment: I'll reiterate @rchome's question: Why are you using a list comprehension? If you just want `api_response["data"]["attributes"].get("percent_complete", '')`, just write that. If you want it to be in a list, put `[]` around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the many comments (thanks `Barmar` and `rchrome`), I have re-writtern my function as follows -

```
def unpack_response():
    api_response = api_call()
    if "meta" not in api_response:
        id_value = "id"
        res1 = [val[id_value] for key, val in api_response.items() if id_value in val]
        id_value = "".join(res1)
        percent_value = "percent_complete"
        res2 = api_response["data"]["attributes"].get("percent_complete", '')
        print(f' Your data requested, associated with ID: {id_value} is {res2} complete!')
        time.sleep(5)
        api_response = api_call()
    if not "meta" in api_response:
        print(api_response)
unpack_response()
```